# Microsoft Translator API (Switching from Statistical to Neural Models)

Tags: python-2.7, bing-api, microsoft-translator, bing-translator-api

I am using the Microsoft Translator API ([Python Scripts](https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/PythonConsole)) and I have noted that it uses the Statistical Machine Translation model by default. However, the Neural Networks Translation Model is more accurate than the Statistical Model. As shown below:

[image: Picture of the two models from the Web App(Compare)]

I would like to use the Neural Networks Model with the API. Seeking guidance on how to make the switch from default Statistical Model to the Neural one...

Answer (score 1):

Using the API, add “category=generalnn” to your call to tell our servers to use the NN models vs. SMT. If the app requests NN for a language that is not supported, it will automatically fall back on the SMT ones.